# Proper template setup Django?

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm a new user of Django.  I've seen a couple ways people are setting up their templates. I would like to get some thoughts on the proper way in case one leads to problems down the road.

The first layout that I've seen is to use multiple template folders. A main one in the root folder and also one under each app directory that you make.

The other way I've seen is to use only one templates folder and just name directories under it which match the name of the apps.

Hopefully that makes sense. Any thoughts on the right way to do it would be appreciated.

Comment: it depends on what you want to build but the current "standard way" is `App`->`template folder`-> `html templates`.

Comment: Okay thanks hans. So I assume you mean the first way I mentioned?

Comment: There's really no "standard". I've seen projects that use it both ways, it's honestly a matter of preference. If look at it from a modular point of view, then having a `templates` folder under each app would make sense. I like thinking modular myself, but I think it's just way easier having all my templates under the same `templates` folder in the root directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "proper" way to do this is debatable, but I'd say that one solid approach is to combine the methods you suggest.

As described in [the tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial03/), as long as `APP_DIRS` is set to `True` (which `manage.py startproject` sets by default), Django will look for templates inside the `templates/` directory of each app. This doesn't require any additional configuration, and has the benefit of keeping app templates within the app directory.

But it is *also* important to put your templates inside a *subdirectory* of `templates/` that matches your app name:

> **Template namespacing**
>
> Now we *might* be able to get away with putting our templates directly in `polls/templates` (rather than creating another `polls` subdirectory), but it would actually be a bad idea. Django will choose the first template it finds whose name matches, and if you had a template with the same name in a *different* application, Django would be unable to distinguish between them. We need to be able to point Django at the right one, and the easiest way to ensure this is by *namespacing* them. That is, by putting those templates inside *another* directory named for the application itself.

So a "proper" location for `app_name`'s templates might be

- `project/`

  - `app_name/`

    - `templates/`

      - `app_name/`

Of course, you can customize this if you wish, but it's still a good idea to namespace your templates.